# HowTo: Unsubscribe from Apollo (subscribeToMore) subscription?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

So I have a subscription as follows that I wish to unsubscription cleanup on:

```html
              <DeleteItem 
                id={item.id}
                urlReferer={urlReferer}
                subscribeToDeleteItems={() =>
                  subscribeToMore({
                    ....
                    }
                  })
                }
              >Delete This Item</DeleteItem>
```

DeleteItem.js

```html
const DeleteItem = props => {
  const {urlReferer} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    props.subscribeToDeleteItems();
  },[urlReferer]);
  ...
  }
...
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So I achieved cleanup by calling an abortController:

```html
  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    props.subscribeToDeleteItems();
    return () => {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  },[urlReferer]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your effect returns a function, React will run it when it is time to clean up. SubscribeToMore returns the unsubscribe function.

```
const subscribeToNewComments = () =>
    subscribeToMore({
      document: MESSAGES_SUBSCRIPTION,
      variables: { channelId },
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        if (!subscriptionData) return prev;
        return Object.assign({}, prev, {
          channelMessages: [
            subscriptionData.data.messageAdded,
            ...prev.channelMessages,
          ],
        });
      },
    });   

React.useEffect(() => {
        let unsub = subscribeToNewComments();
        return () => {
          unsub();
        };
      }, [channelId]);
```